# encrypt decrypt credit card no

Tags: zend-framework, encryption, strlen

I have some credit card and routing number stored in $credit and $routing_respectively. Before I insert it to the database I need to ENCRYPT and while displaying it I need to decrypt it.I am using the ZEND framework. Is there any in built function I can use?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The requirements for storing credit card data are a little too complex to solve completely using an SO question.

I suggest you take a look at the [PCI-DSS requirements for storing credit card data](https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/security_standards/documents.php?assocation=PCI%20DSS) since the encryption part may be simple, but the key management and authorization procedures sure aren't.

Comment: I am using it for internal purposes..All i need is to encrpt it and store it. I do not need it for any kind of authorization.

Comment: I'm afraid PCI-DSS still applies for any storage of sensitive card- or card holder data, including for internal use.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question: There is no encryption component in Zend Framework 1.x. Zend Framework 2 will have a Zend_Crypt component, but it seems to only be doing hashing and ssl at the moment.
[Zf2 Zend_Crypt Code Repository](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/tree/master/library/Zend/Crypt)

Answer (score 0):

You should use PHP [mcrypt](http://php.net/mcrypt) extension to do that. Just for notice, Magento Ecommerce uses mcrypt to secure credit card information.

Anyway, I still recommend that you follow Joachim Isaksson's link.